# aws describe instances showing empty list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using the AWS API to create a direct http request to AWS EC2. Whenever I try to do DescribeInstances I get this:

```
<DescribeInstancesResponse xmlns="http://ec2.amazonaws.com/doc/2016-11-15/">
    <requestId>133ec145-9495-41bc-ba15-bc54bf6d4d5b</requestId>
    <reservationSet/>
</DescribeInstancesResponse>
```

If try to do StartInstances - it says non existing ID .
But for DescribeRegions it is working fine. Where do I go wrong ?

Comment: Do you have any EC2 instance in the region?

Comment: Hi Krisha, I do (eu-central-1) , but as the users are part of IAM and they are zoneless, I am not sure why I cant get to list the instances. I added all possible groups in there (6 in total) but same thing... Only DescribeRegions work, although I strongly believe I am authenticated , I am unsure why I cant see the instances or start/stop one of them. Really weird. I think its rights on the AWS side over the user, but havent seen yet what else is needed to do this.

Comment: Try `DescribeAvailabilityZones`.  Chances seem high that you are sending the request to the wrong region, which will become evident when you see the list of AZs returned.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that you have no ec2 instances running in the region your are querying. Make sure the region parameter references a region in which you do have ec2 instances.